# How spring-roo generate skeleton application works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I'm curious about how the spring-roo generated application works, I have some questions:

1. Where is the servlets?
2. Where is the code link the domain object to GUI?
3. Where is the code instantiate the spring POJO?
4. Where is data persistence code?
5. Why the domain class(bean) is not declared in spring configuration file?

Could anyone help me to understand the structure of the skeleton project? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [architecture](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html) section of the spring roo reference documentation has info that would answer most of your questions.  It will be easier to understand if you have some knowledge of spring, jpa and aop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer after some study, I'm not sure if it is correct. Any comment or correction is greatly appreciated.

> 1.Where is the servlets?

Roo generated project use spring mvc as presentation layer, Spring will search all class annotated with "@controller" as the controller class.

> 2.Where is the code link the domain object to GUI?

Domain object are classes annotated with "@Entity", roo also add "@RooJpaActiveRecord" to indicate DAO functionality.

> 3.Where is the code instantiate the spring POJO?

All the domain object are instantiated through the database queries, which lives in *_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj.

> 4.Where is data persistence code?

Answered in Q2.

> 5.Why the domain class(bean) is not declared in spring configuration file?

Spring automatically detect domain object through annotation "@Entity"